# My Git-Fu needs help. rm -r undo

Tags: git

Switched directories, though a bunch of other changes were on another branch, rm -r the entire app/ directory, now I'm screwed.

https://github.com/GeerSwitch/penbuilders/commit/20c5111364f0c8369669d2347d35f4b83371e6fb

See that branch there?  See the 2k+ deletions? I suck at git.

I've tried resetting the head, resetting to previous commit hashes, and still, those files aren't back.

Can someone save me?  ls-files --deleted shows nothing, I can see them in the link above, and will copy+paste if I have to.

Comment: did you try `git reset --hard a1b043b2939994f1d94163ec34ebc35a011a1ff1` ?

Comment: Just reset to the parent of that commit you've posted the link to. GIthub says it's: a1b043b2939994f1d94163ec34ebc35a011a1ff1 . So `git reset --hard a1b043b2939994f1d94163ec34ebc35a011a1ff1` should get you there. If you want a new commit that reverses the deletes, you can then use `git revert`.

Comment: Note that you don't need to specify the full hash. Typically the first 6 or 7 digits is enough to uniquely identify a commit: `git reset --hard a1b043b`

Answer (score 1):

The files are still there, short of wiping your entire GitHub repository you can always get them back.  You could try a [`git revert`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert):

```
git revert 20c51
```

This will create a new commit that reverses all the changes in commit `20c51`.  This is the safest approach since it does not rewrite any of the existing history.  It's also the *preferred* approach if you are working with any collaborators.

On the other hand, if you want to "play with fire" you can do a [`git rebase --interactive 20c51~1`](http://git-scm.com/book/ch3-6.html) and then `edit` the offending commit(s).  This will alter the history and can cause you to lose your existing work if not used carefully.

Comment: Will deleting the repo give me everything? This particular project isn't one I need git for really, just wantes to use it and learn it. I tried a variety of commit reversions and my app/ dir wasn't back.

Comment: Deleting the repo won't perform any action by itself. Inside the directory do as Rufflewind suggested and you will get your files back.

Comment: You should look at both `git status` and `git log` and try to figure out what exactly the current state of your repository is.  Otherwise it's very hard to tell where you're stuck at.  If you need help deciphering what's going on, feel free to paste the output of `git status` and `git log`.  Also note that the GitHub repository is not automatically synchronized with your local repository, so changes your make there are not visible on GitHub without a corresponding `git push`.

Comment: Also, deleting your local repository won't change anything because your remote (GitHub) repository has already received those offending changes.

Comment: So far some of these worked ish, but nothing that reverted all the deletions. Is there a way to remove git from the equation so I don't spend all day tomorrow rewriting everything?

Comment: (1) If the file was never committed to your repository there is very little hope of recovering them.  There is a small possibility of recovering some dangling blobs in the repository if you checked them into the index but not fully committed them, though.  (2) I don't understand what you mean by "remove git from the equation".  If you don't execute any git commands and ignore the `.git` subdirectory then it is essentially "out of the equation" but I don't think that's what you meant ...

Answer (score 0):

You can restore to the previous commit with `git reset --hard a1b043b`.

Note: git reset --hard must be used very carefully: it will completely wipe your local changes and will alter the location of the current branch. Also, if you are collaborating with other developers, it will cause problems if someone else has based work off of the branch you are resetting.

Comment: Note: `git reset --hard` must be used *very carefully*: it will completely wipe your local changes and will alter the location of the current branch.

Comment: @Rufflewind Added the warning to my answer. (It appears this is a single-developer project and I assume that the dev hasn't made any other changes since deleting all these files. Still the warning is very appropriate.)